# Inconsistent access specifiers in STL GCC implementation

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, containers

While reading about the implementation of STL containers in `GCC`, I noticed a discrepancy in the use of access specifiers in the base classes. Specifically, some classes (`_Vector_base`) are completely public, and therefore allow access to any member from the outside, while others (`_Deque_base`) are completely protected, and therefore allow access to members only to derived or friend classes. Moreover, there are classes (`_List_base`) that have a partly public and partly protected interface. In this analysis, I preferred to exclude containers that were introduced in C++11 as they may have been designed and implemented following a slightly different perspective than the containers that were already present in previous standards.

I would like to know, especially from those who have actively participated in the implementation of the above containers, whether there is a consistent technical choice for these differences or these are just ideas from different programming teams. Furthermore, I would like to know whether these choices were based on a broader reasoning, such as reusing of the code in other modules or providing a greater flexibility of the interfaces in view of future updates, or were only based on immediate needs.

Comment: Does `class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>` help? It means that the public members of `_Vector_base` are _not_ generally available from the outside, unless you make a class that inherits from `vector` of course.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, pre-C++11 containers were actually implemented such that all base classes are derived through protected inheritance, and therefore appear to follow a unique design choice. This apparent contradiction confuses me even more: if on the one hand all the derived classes use the same access specifier for inheritance, on the other hand the base classes use different access specifiers in their interfaces.

Comment: The base classes are an implementation detail that you were never expected to notice and certainly never use.  So I suspect (without proof) that it was wholly down to the preferences of whoever did a particular implementation.

Comment: The likelyhood of anyone who was extensively involved in the implementation of libstdc++ being a Stackoverflow C++ regular are slim to none. There might be one or two people here who've dabbled in some part of libstdc++, it's been a collaborative effort over many years by a huge number of people, and it is unlikely that any one person has the collective domain knowledge across the entire set of C++ templates.

Comment: Just to add 2c to what already @MarkRansom wrote: never use anything that starts from double underscore `__` or underscore and capital letter like `_Vector_base`. Such names are explicitly forbidden to use by C++ standard. They are reserved to compiler (including std library) vendor.

Comment: @PiotrNycz, you are right. However, my question focuses on the internal dynamics of `libstdc++`. My perplexity did not arise from the use of a naming convention in order to suggest their use as private or protected attributes (Python-style), but from the fact that this naming convention is  or is not strengthened by the access specifiers. This inconsistency confuses me.

Comment: Proper using of public and private (encapsulation) is not a goal. This is just tool. Very useful in code that is indented to be used by many users who are not very familiar with overall design - just to avoid problems with maintainability. E.g. maintainability is a goal to achieve. But this code starting with __ and _Capital are indented to be used only by small number of experts - so these experts can freely not follow encapsulation if they can achieve other goals like easy of use or compilation speed or performance.